# Jetty Configuration - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory

Tags: java, configuration, jetty

i'm trying to test some configurations for Jetty regarding [Proxy / Load Balancer Connection](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html#d0e4404) and at the Proxy Protocol sections there is an example with:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
      <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
      <Arg name="factories">
        <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
          <Item>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory"/>
          </Item>
          <Item>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
              <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
            </New>
          </Item>
        </Array>
      </Arg>
      <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
      <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" default="80" /></Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

The issue is that jetty throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory when starting because the ProxyConnectionFactory class is not in the libs.
Searching for it, I found out it is in jetty-server, for jetty 9.3.5 (for java 8), but I'm using  version 9.2.7.

Does anyone know if this configuration is available in another package for my version 9.2.7? I haven't found anything in the docs regarding the availability of ProxyConnectionFactory, prior to the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.eclipse.jetty.server.ProxyConnectionFactory` was [introduced in Jetty 9.3.0.M2](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/a308c087edae79917b40dbc8e1b5f0c0b3b15b12#diff-746d31c20b2c259bccaaf2b9151b6030), as part of a general support for the PROXY protocol.

Sorry, it is not available in the Jetty 9.2.x series.